# library("ReporteRs") error: object 'readPNG' was not exported by 'namespace:png'

Tags: r, reporters

I've been trying to load *library*("ReporteRs"), but to no avail.

It returns the error:

```
package or namespace load failed for ‘ReporteRs’
object 'readPNG' was not exported by 'namespace:png'
```

I have been able to load rJava, ReporteRsjars and png. Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you installed this package?

Comment: Yes, I did it via install.packages("ReporteRs"). Got the message: "package ‘ReporteRs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked."

Comment: What version of R you are using? I R 3.5.0 on a Windows 10 machine. I just downloaded and loaded the `ReporteRs 0.8.10`. It works.

Comment: Hm, I'm also using R 3.5.0 and Windows 10. Did you do it via install.packages?

Comment: Yes, I did. Perhaps try to install and load the `PNG` package because that is the package with the `readPNG` function.

Comment: Try install.packages("ReporteRs", dependencies = TRUE)?